# Speeding up bluetooth device detection by Windows 7

Tags: windows, usb, bluetooth, kvm-switch, dongle

I have 3 computers, one on Windows 7 x64, the other also on Windows 7 x64, the last one on MacOS Snow Leopard, connected onto a Belkin KVM switch. On that switch, I have a BlueTooth USB dongle that is used to connect my BlueTooth mouse. NOTE : these computers are not linked each other, and won't be linked.

When switching back and forth from one computer to another, especially talking about the Windows one (I didn't test with the Mac), the BT connection has been lost during the switch, because the computer do not see the bluetooth dongle any more, so my mouse cursor is frozen. I have to wait some 10-30 seconds that the computer can see again the dongle, and then the mouse, to be able to use it.

Is there a way to make that BlueTooth detection update faster, or force Windows to keep the BT connection event if it do not see the dongle anymore, so I don't have to wait so long ?

PS : I've tried to install the latest manufacturer drivers, but it's worse. I can wait forever before the mouse / dongle is detected again after switch. Windows generic drivers do a better job, so I kept them.

PS2 : The dongle is a Belkin one, the short one (F8T016 I guess, but the reference not visible on the dongle itself)

PS3 : I tried with other USB Bluetooth dongles, but still the same problem.
I tried with other KVM switches, still the same problem.
Tried to pu the BT dongle on another USB port onto the KVM switch, still the same.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the dongle more then anything.

Comment: @Ramhound:do you think so ? Why ? It's the Belkin one, the short one (F8T016 I guess, but the reference not visible on the dongle itself)

Comment: @Ramhound:I could make some more tests since I asked the question with other dongles. Your comment seems to be the good answer, as some dongles seems to be more quickly recognized than others. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: You want me to answer a 7 year old question with, “it’s a hardware issue”, it seems like your in the best position to answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramhound comment is the answer :
"Sounds like a problem with the dongle more then anything."

I could make some more tests since I asked the question with other dongles. Some dongles seems to be more quickly recognized than others.